# CSS3 or Jquery: popup of a thumbnail image when the thumbnail is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I need to list the thumbnail images on a page, all of which have fixed height and width. Once I hover any of them, I want the larger image display at a fixed position, i.e. top:50px and left:50px within its wrapper. The size of the larger image is also fixed, i.e. width:100px, and height: 100px.

I followed the instruction on 
http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-popup.htm
but I could not figure out to put the larger image at a fixed position.

I would appreciate if you could help me in this
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed, places the image(element) an amount of pixels based on the whole window. Not to the wrapper.

Position absolute places the image an amount of pixels based on its wrapper.

So try adding this.

```
.larger-image {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     left: 50px;
}
```

If for some reason it doesn't work, please post your relevant code.